# How can I create a dynamic order by expression for a query

Tags: python, psycopg3

I am testing with PostgreSQL and psycopg and have the following code:

my table is called `cars` and have columns: `brand`, `model`, `year`, `price`, `id`

```py
import psycopg

k = input("")

conn = psycopg.connect(
    dbname="Testing",
    user="postgres",
    password="my_password",
    host="localhost",
    port="5432"
)

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY %s DESC;", (k,))  # Corrected the query here


rows = cur.fetchall()


for row in rows:
    print(row)

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

but when I enter `price` in terminal I get this

```
price
('bmw', 'X5', 2000, 1000, 1)
('lada', 'granta', 2020, 1000, 2)
('Audi', 'A8', 2030, 200000, 3)
('audi', 'A6', 2008, 200000, 4)
('a', 'b', 2000, 2000, 5)
('mercedes', 'c-klasse', 2019, 20000, 6)
('mercedes', 'c-klasse', 2019, 20000, 7)
('Audi', 'Q7', 2020, 300000, 8)
```

so data is not being sorted. How to fix it

tried to replace k by 'price' but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter binding only exists for values, like integers, strings, dates etc. A column name is not a value; you cannot use parameter binding for identifiers. Since `k` gets bound to the placeholder as a value, your query is equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY 'price' DESC;
```

Since the column `'price'` (unlike the column `price`, or equivalently `"price"`) always contains the same value (namely, the string `'price'`), the ordering clause has no effect.

You have to put the identifier into the SQL command manually. However, given that putting user input directly into SQL compromises security, it would be better to find another method (e.g. a dropdown, with dropdown values mapping back to column names, or at least strict validation).

For example, in the toy code you posted,

```
columns = { "brand", "model", "year", "price", "id" }
while True:
    k = input("Sort field:")
    if k in columns:
        break
    print("Invalid field")

# ...

cur.execute(f'SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY "{k}" DESC;')
```

The double quotes in `"{k}"` are not necessary here, but are a good practice, just in case a valid column name happens to be a keyword like `where` or include a character not valid in plain identifiers, like `First Name`.

EDIT: As Adrian Klaver notes in a comment, `psycopg.sql` can compose SQL safely, so this should be the prefered method (though it is specific to `psycopg`, i.e. limited to PostgreSQL):

```
query = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY {} DESC")
cur.execute(query.format(sql.Identifier(k)))
```

Comment: Do not encourage SQL injection by using string interpolation when there is a safe alternative available namely the `psycopg2` module [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html)

Comment: 1) It is also available in `psycopg(3)` per [psycopg3 sql](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/sql.html) 2) The OP is working with Postgres, so I don't see why you need to qualify the answer e.g. *... limited to PostgreSQL*.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Because SO is a knowledge base, and I am not writing for OP alone. AFAIK no SQL driver can use parameter binding for identifiers, so that part of the answer is general, not PostgreSQL-specific. If someone comes along and looks for the solution for the same problem but they are working with e.g. MySQL, it would be nice if it was clear that `psycopg2.sql` method will not help them.

Comment: FWIW, the OP is using psycopg3, not psycopg2.