# Why is an invalid order by expression placeholder ignored in a prepared statement

Tags: postgresql

Given this table and data:

```
test# create table t (c int);
CREATE TABLE
test# insert into t (c) values (1), (3), (2);
INSERT 0 3
```

If I try to query the table with an invalid order by expression in a statement I get an error:

```
test# select c from t order by 'c' desc;
ERROR:  non-integer constant in ORDER BY
LINE 1: select c from t order by 'c' desc;
```

which is logged:

```
2024-02-14 11:26:31.734 GMT test user [5047]LOG:  statement: select c from t order by 'c' desc;
2024-02-14 11:26:31.734 GMT test user [5047]ERROR:  non-integer constant in ORDER BY at character 26
2024-02-14 11:26:31.734 GMT test user [5047]STATEMENT:  select c from t order by 'c' desc;
```

However if I bind the invalid value to a prepared statement, there is no error and the rows are returned *unordered*:

```
test# prepare q (varchar) as select c from t order by $1;
PREPARE
test# execute q ('c');
 c 
═══
 1
 3
 2
(3 rows)
```

No error is logged:

```
2024-02-14 15:18:17.626 GMT test user [5047]LOG:  statement: prepare q (varchar) as select c from t order by $1;
2024-02-14 15:18:29.834 GMT test user [5047]LOG:  statement: execute q ('c');
2024-02-14 15:18:29.834 GMT test user [5047]DETAIL:  prepare: prepare q (varchar) as select c from t order by $1;
```

Using the `\bind` meta-command likewise does not error and produces the same result:

```
test# select c from t order by $1 desc \bind 'c' \g
 c 
═══
 1
 3
 2
(3 rows)
```

Logs:

```
2024-02-14 15:22:31.123 GMT test user [5047]LOG:  execute <unnamed>: select c from t order by $1 desc 
2024-02-14 15:22:31.123 GMT test user [5047]DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'c'
```

Why doesn't the prepared statement fail with the same error as in the first statement?

Background context: I noticed in this Python [psycopg3](/questions/tagged/psycopg3) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77986062/5320906), originally tagged as [psycopg2](/questions/tagged/psycopg2)<sup>*</sup>, the statement `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY %s DESC;", (k,))` raises the above error when executed by `psycopg2`, which binds parameters client-side, but succeeds, returning an unordered response, using `psycopg3`, which lets the server perform the binding.

---

<sup>*</sup> `psycopg2` and `psycopg3` are Python connection packages (drivers) for PostgreSQL. Both are wrappers around `libpq` as I understand it.

Comment: single quotes are used to determine strings. what you encounter is some atp cpnvertion, so don't use single quetes

Comment: Is your database DB2, and why do you want to order by a string constant?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The db is Postgres. I don't want to order by a string constant, but I want to know why I get an error (as I'd expect) in one case but not the other.

Comment: @nbk What is "atp" in this context?

Comment: the string you send to the prepared statement is inserted without qutes, that why it is working. so **never** use single quotes

Comment: @nbk "Don't use single quotes" is great advice, but isn't really what I'm asking about here.

Answer (score 1):

Order by clause need `sort_expression`.
A `sort_expression` can also be the column label or number of an output column.

Some examples:
In this query, `c` is output column name, output sorted by column c

```
select * from test
order by c
```

In this query, `1` is number of output column, output sorted by output column 1

```
select * from test
order by 1
```

In this query, `'c'` not is output column name, therefore must be number of output column

```
select * 
from test
order by 'c'

ERROR:  non-integer constant in ORDER BY
LINE 3: order by 'c'
```

Next example. `'c'||'a'`  is sort_expression. There no error and, no ordering :) because expression is constant.

```
select * from test
order by 'c'||'a'
```

There `2-1`  is `sort_expression`

```
select * from test
order by 2-1
```

For prepared statement `$1` is `only sort_expression`, not column name, not output column number. By design, this is `constant` expression - no sorting

```
select * from test
order by $1
```

For conditional sorting you can

```
select * 
from test
order by case when $1='c' then c
              when $1='d' then d
         else e
         end
```

Comment: I'm not asking why the statement errors, I'm asking why there is no error when executing the _prepared statement_.

Comment: when executing the prepared statement, value ``'c'`` is interpreted as ``sort_expression``. And this is ``valid`` sort_expression. Case of ``order by 'c'`` value ``'c'`` is interpreted as column number - must be integer value.

Comment: "By design, this is constant expression - no sorting" -> is this documented anywhere?

Comment: When sorting a constant value, all rows have the same order, i.e. there is no sorting.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter should not be used as column name or table name ever. If you want to do it, you should to use dynamic SQL. The clause `ORDER BY` is difficult, because (naturally) supports column names, but it can supports any expressions too - but the order is based on the result on expression, and result of expression cannot be used as name of sorted column. `ORDER BY` supports integer values there, and then it means sort by column on position.

You can check `EXPLAIN` of prepared statement:

```
(2024-02-14 17:14:39) postgres=# explain analyze execute q ('c');
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                           QUERY PLAN                                           │
╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..35.50 rows=2550 width=36) (actual time=0.016..0.018 rows=3 loops=1) │
│ Planning Time: 0.097 ms                                                                        │
│ Execution Time: 0.038 ms                                                                       │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(3 rows)
```

There is not `sort` node.

The reason, why the error is not raised in this case is probably effect of some heuristic for that separates processing for constants and expressions. In this concept the constant is some different from immutable expression. I think it depends on implementation of SQL parser (based on bison). When you use `$1` - query parameter, it is expression (it is allowed), but because it is immutable expression, then it is ignored.

```
(2024-02-14 17:23:32) postgres=# select c from t order by 'c' desc;
ERROR:  non-integer constant in ORDER BY
LINE 1: select c from t order by 'c' desc;
                                 ^
(2024-02-14 17:29:28) postgres=# select c from t order by 'c'::varchar desc;
┌───┐
│ c │
╞═══╡
│ 1 │
│ 3 │
│ 2 │
└───┘
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Ah, I hadn't though to run `EXPLAIN`.  I see that `select c from t order by true` produces the same plan, so I suppose the expression gets elided somehow.  I'd be interested to hear what the devs have to say.

Comment: @snakecharmerb - described behaviour is based SQL parser implementation. It is too primitive, and disallow raw literal constants (in SQL) in parser stage. Any other are allowed, what can be messy - probably it should not be stricter now due compatibility